# Null Pointer Exception on toDF()

Tags: apache-spark

Within Map I'm taking few columns and trying to create DF.

```java
val columns : List[caseclass_Name] = List(CaseClass(id, id)) //Case Class
val splDF = columns.toDF() //DataFrame
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf.getConf(SQLConf.scala:638)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf.dataFrameEagerAnalysis(SQLConf.scala:573)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:432)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.localSeqToDataFrameHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:164)
at package.ObjectName$.Method(Object_name.scala:322)
at)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.processInputs(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:505)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.<init>(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:686)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:95)
```

Comment: This seems to be relevant, but it does not solve the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20299